# How to find all higher version of sql file in a particular directory and apply one by one, if any import fails revert back to original one

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I am really struggling to find a solution for the following problem , If someone could help using bash script

Here is the use case :-

1. I have one table defined in myssql (db.version) which gives me the current version of mysql, so suppose i import dbv1.sql , db.version updates it to 1.
2. I have to find current version of sql (which i did already)
3. I have to search for all the sql file which is greater than v1 , lets say v2 , v3 , v4 ...and so on..  in a directory db/  and import those sql files one by one .
4. If any import fails , mysql version should stay at v1 only.

I am looking for this solution in bash.

word done so for from my side.. for a single file

```
myvar=$(mysql -h$hosttr -D<dbname> -u$user -p$passwd -s <<<"SELECT dbVersion FROM version" ) 

echo "Current version is $myvar"
myvar=$((myvar+1))
dbV=dbVersion"$myvar.sql"
echo $dbV
file="db/$dbV"
pwd
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
    echo "$file found."
    cd db/
    mysql -h$hosttr -D<dbname> -u$user -p$passwd < "$dbV"

else
    echo "$file not found."
fi
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: @Cyrus I have made the changes that i did for single file

Comment: You have several issues/questions here. At least 2 questions worth: how to find and select the appropriate files and how to get back to the initial version of the database if any import fails. First one is tough enough, but the second needs way more details than what is contained in this question. I suggest you split your question in more manageable chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer, the part done in bash.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the version from the database
myvar=$(mysql -h$hosttr -D<dbname> -u$user -p$passwd -s <<<"SELECT dbVersion FROM version" )

# Get the list versions to apply
versions=$(find db -name "dbVersion*.sql" -print | sed 's/.*dbVersion\(.*\)\.sql/\1/' | sort -n)

for V in $versions
do
    if [ "$myvar" -lt $V ]
    then
        echo $V
    fi
done
```

The `$versions` list contains the version numbers that are greater than the version read from the database.

- `find`: get a list of files that match the pattern
- `sed`: extract the version number from the file names
- `sort -n`: sort by numerical value

Then to apply each file to the database.

**Method 1**

1 take a backup of the database
 2 apply the version scripts
 3 each script is applied one by one.  If all goes well, you are done.
 4 If any fails, you restore the backup

**Method 2**

1 You create a new sql script file
 2 The first line starts a transaction
 3 Then you concatenate each script into that main script
 4 The last line is a commit
 5 On an error, you rollback instead of commit

For that method, I suggest you talk to a DBA to make sure it is ok (or post to https://dba.stackexchange.com/).  If my memory is good, if you run a `mysql` command for each file, it auto-commits changes for each file.  So you would not be able to return to the original database version.